# how to support composite column names in CQL3 with empty prefixes

Tags: cassandra, cql3

In thrift, you could have composite columns of the form string:bytearray and integer:bytearray and decimal:bytearray.  Once defined, you could store values in an integer:bytearray like so

```
{empty}.somebytearray
{empty}.somebytearray
5.somebytearray
10.somebytearray
```

I could then query and get all the columns that were prefixed with {empty}.

This seems it cannot be done in CQL3 so we cannot port our code to CQL3 at this time?  Is there a ticket for this or will it every be resolved.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Wasn't this already discussed on the mailing list? http://markmail.org/message/suhmwqbwulz2hrsm?q=is+this+correct%2C+thrift+unportable+to+CQL3

Comment: ah, there is my missing thread as this came up again.....I couldn't remember where that was....we still have not solved that issue and I was trying to send that to someone to finally fix this so we can use CQL3

Answer (score 0):

The empty column name isn't null.

A good example is the cql3 row marker which looks like this when exported via sstable2json:

```
                               //<--- row marker ----->
{"key": "6b657937","columns": [["","",1375804090248000], ["value","value7",1375804090248000]]}
```

It looks like the column name is empty, but its a byte array with 3 components. So say we want to add a column with an empty name:

```
                       // column name
columnFamily.addColumn(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[3]), value, timestamp);
```

Comment: ok, that is how to add the column with empty name....how do we query for all columns with an empty name?  thanks, Dean